# strptime not working for below format

Tags: python, strptime

I have used the below format which is being read from a log file, The formatter used is matching the DateTime format. not sure why it is still erroring.
 - ValueError: time data " '2018-01-01 10:00:00'" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

```
f = open("log.txt", 'w')
f.write("UID, SID, LogTime\n")
f.write("1, 1, '2018-01-01 10:00:00'\n")
f.write("1, 1, '2018-01-01 10:30:00'\n")
f.write("1, 1, '2018-01-01 11:30:00'\n")
f.close()
x = open("log.txt", 'r')

print (x.read())
x.close()

import numpy as np 
from datetime import datetime
a = open("log.txt", 'r+')
temp = None
header = a.readline()
for line in a:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split(',')
    print (columns)
    UID = columns[0]
    SID = columns[1]
    print (columns[2])
    LogTime = datetime.strptime(columns[2],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    a.write(','+LogTime-temp)
    temp = LogTime
```

Comment: Can you provide a more specific code example?

Comment: the above code yields error in my description, format doesnot match!

Comment: this is solved, Thank you, everyone, for the inputs!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your format has quotes around the datetimes, plus a leading space:

```
f.write("1, 1, '2018-01-01 10:00:00'\n")
```

But your parser doesn't strip those quotes and space off, and your `strptime` isn't expecting them. And, while `2018-01-01 10:00:00` would match your format, `'2018-01-01 10:00:00'` does not.

You can solve this in a few ways:

- Use the `csv` module for reading (or numpy, since you're already importing it), which will handle CSV quoting and spaces automatically.
- Do the quote handling manually—e.g., `timestamp = columns[2].strip().strip("'")`.
- Add the space and quotes to the `strptime` format: `datetime.strptime(columns[2]," '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'")`

The first one seems by far the cleanest, but they'll all work.

---

Of course once you fix that, you're going to have another problem: `a.write(','+LogTime-temp)` is trying to add a string `','` to a `datetime` object, and then subtract `None` from the result. None of those types are compatible, so this makes no sense.

If you were trying to diff subsequent times, then you have to:

- Handle the first row specially, since it has no previous time;
- Handle the first *diff* specially too, since it has no preceding `,`;
- Subtract the times to get a `timedelta` *before* trying to attach one of them to a string;
- Either convert the diff to a string with `str` instead of just adding it to `','`, or, maybe better, use an f-string (or `format`) instead of adding strings.

This should be enough to get you started, but it's not the complete program:

```
temp = None
for line in a:
    # ... up to LogTime = ...
    if temp is not None:
        diff = LogTime - temp
        print(diff)
    temp = LogTime
```

---

And then you're trying to write to the file at the same time you're reading it, which is just going to make a horrible mess. You'll read one line, then overwrite the next line—or, more likely, half the next line, or the next two and a third lines, or whatever, then read the next line after that… What you want to do is one of:

- Write to a *different* file (you can `os.replace` it over the original one when you're done if needed);
- Just build the rows you want to write into a list, then `close` the file, re`open` the same file, and write out the list of rows.

Comment: This is weird, I tried the manual method and it doesn't delete the first ('), so the new string is like below '2018-01-01:10:00:00

Comment: I want calculate running difference of timestamps and add to the same file, for the first record there is no timestamp to compare with. but second row will have "1800" added to it as the time difference between second rows and first row timestamps.

Comment: @TrendingNow You clearly did something wrong, but I can't really debug _what_ you did wrong without seeing your code. Maybe you did the two `strip` calls in reverse order?

Comment: @TrendingNow After you solve your first problem, you should be able to work out how to do the diffing, or at least get farther and then ask a new question wherever you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading this value " '2018-01-01 11:30:00'" and not this "2018-01-01 11:30:00"

Just try

```
LogTime = datetime.strptime(columns[2].strip(" '"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to include quotes, so instead of "2018-01-01 11:30:00" you have "'2018-01-01 11:30:00'" in the variable.

You can strip those in many ways, some ideas below:

```
LogTime = datetime.strptime(columns[2],"'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'")

LogTime = datetime.strptime(columns[2].strip("'"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

or use the csv module,